# Can someone help me identify why C# tooltips show when they shouldn't?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have tool tips running on a C# form and i have a checkbox to disable them showing up.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        Tool_Tips = false;
    }
    else
        Tool_Tips = true;
}
```

where `Tool_Tips` is a Global public bool.

each time I hover over a button I use the code:

```
private void Edge_Down_B_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Tool_Tips)
    {
        Tool_Tip(Tool_Help.Edge_Down, Edge_Down_B);
    }
}
```

my problem is that i have 4 buttons out of like 30 that will display a tooltip regardless of the boolean value. If i put a breakpoint in their code it works correctly, but if i remove the breakpoint their tooltip will show up when it shouldnt. I did clean build of release mode, rebuilt the project and tried debug mode and they continue to show a tooltip when they shouldnt.

I even changed the code of those 4 buttons to look like:

```
private void BlackandWhite_B_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Tool_Tips)
    {
        if (!checkBox1.Checked)
            Tool_Tip(Tool_Help.BlackWhite, BlackandWhite_B);
    }
}
```

and they still show up in normal running mode. they won't show up if i place a breakpoint in.

Can anyone tell me why?

EDIT:
if i run my program, it will start with tooltips disabled with the checkbox checked. I will uncheck the box and i will see tooltips. if i recheck the box to disable the tooltips, the tooltips i have viewed will still show up even though they are disabled.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't just a hangover from the last time it got set (before you cleared the checkbox)? IIRC many tooltips are stored in a keyed collection. If you don't clear this, they are still set.

Comment: im not sure. i have all my mouseovers call Tool_Tip()  which is a function i created:            public void Tool_Tip(string help, Button bt)
        {
            if (Tool_Tips)
            {
                ToolTip Tip = new ToolTip();
                Tip.ReshowDelay = 0;
                Tip.InitialDelay = 0;
                Tip.AutoPopDelay = 0;
                Tip.AutomaticDelay = 0;
                Tip.Show(help, bt, 3000);
            }
        } and this does the actual showing. 30 some buttons call this and only ~4 have issues with it

Comment: i added 
                Tip.Dispose();
                Tip.RemoveAll(); after Tip.Show() and did not stop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, make sure there aren't any other event handlers attached to those 4 buttons' Click.

after that try changing your method as:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Tool_Tips  = !checkBox1.Checked;
    }
```

the events might had gotten fired before the checkbox have been checked.

and if that did not work either, inside your Tool_Tip method write:

```
if (checkbox1.Checked) return;
```

and if none of those helped, shoot me in the head :D!

before shooting me, do this:
in debug mode disable(or delete) all your breakpoints and put one just in your Tool_Tip method's first line.

make the bug show up and your breakpoint be hit.
then from the debug menu, open Call Stack and check that from where your method has been called. this might lead you to the problem, because I think you method is being called from an unwanted point of code.

Comment: it is still doing it even after i commented out my old code and set Tool_Tips = !checkBox1.checked. and i added in the if(checkBox1.checked)return; but i dont has a gunz :P

Comment: it has to be remembering it somewhere. if i put in breakpoints it works fine but just running it in debug or release they still show up

Comment: On startup the checkbox is set to Checked which means no tooltips. no tooltips appear. if i uncheck the box, the tooltips appear, correct so far. if i then recheck the box, the Tool_Tips variable is false and thats when it shows the stuff incorrectly

Comment: did you add `Application.DoEvents();`?

Comment: yes i did.          private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Tool_Tips = !checkBox1.Checked;
            //if (checkBox1.Checked)
            //{
            //    Tool_Tips = false;
            //}
            //else
            //    Tool_Tips = true;
        }  i commented out my old code and put the new code above it

Comment: ok, before shooting me, I have edited my post. try the last one as well

Comment: i put a breakpoint in and it never fires under the glitch. but if i remove the breakpoint it does run the glitch

Comment: After i removed the breakpoint, i Unchecked the box, activated the affected tooltip and then i Rechecked the box. i checked the affected tooltip and it popped up but the others did not.

Comment: time to being shot, sorry I cannot provide any more help from this side of the word :(

Comment: i dont have a gun i wont shoot you :P i just appreciate the help

Comment: it seems like it doesnt like my templated tooltip procedure. it likes to have a global tooltip instanced that just is hidden or shown.